# Find missing file in an process openfile request on Windows

Tags: filesystems, window, process-explorer

I have an thid-party EXE that doesn't work and it fails with a generic "File not found" exception and I cannot understand what it is looking for.
Unfortunately I cannot use ProcessExplorer or something like that because the process closes itself after this error.

How can I log filesystem request from a specific process to find what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) or something like that. ProcMon performs a continuous capture and does not depend on precise timing.

To make monitoring easier, right-click & exclude unwanted events by their process name (e.g. exclude 'Explorer.exe'), by their result code (e.g. exclude 'SUCCESS'), and so on.